# How to view the image of .PBRT file

Tags: graphics, rendering, raytracing, pbrt

I am new to using PBRT (physically based ray tracing) .. How can I view the image of a `.pbrt` file.

I have done the below steps from command prompt:

```
set PBRT_SEARCHPATH=C:\pbrt-1.03-lc\bin
    cd C:\pbrt-1.03-lc\scenes\Conference
    ..\..\bin\pbrt.exe conference.pbrt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A .pbrt file is a scene description file or a file containing a triangle mesh.

This file is only a description of something that is used to render an image with.

To render the image you have to run the \bin\pbrt.exe in the following way:

\bin\pbrt.exe conference.pbrt --outfile conference.tga

This command will render the image and save it to the file named conference.tga